# points clustering

Tags: c#, algorithm

Assuming there are 10,000 points with x and y coordination. Many of them are close together like below picture : 
[image]

To reduce size of the data I am trying to pick one point from each 10 closest points together.I mean divide points into ten part categories and pick one from each category

What algorithm or method do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need exactly 10 points per cluster, you can use something like k-means clustering and then for each cluster, choose the point that is the closest to the cluster center. You can set the number of clusters k to be around N/10 where N is your total number of points so that you get roughly 10 points per cluster. k-means clustering usually runs very fast and generally gives good results, often global optimum, although convergence is to a local optimum. If you insist on having exactly 10 points per cluster, then you can quickly compute the 20-30 nearest neighbors for each point using a knn algorithm e.g. based on kd-trees as implemented in knnsearch in matlab. Then choose a point and make a cluster out of it with its 9 nearest neighbors. You can even choose the point that has the closest 9th neighbor if you want to start with the tightest clusters possible. Then remove the 10 points from your nearest neighbor lists and total list of points and repeat. If you ever get fewer than 9 nearest neighbors for a point, you can quickly get the next 20-30 nearest neighbors by repeating knn search for that query point, assuming you still have the kd-tree for the points stored in memory. Total running time should be much faster than O(N^2) if you store reverse look up tables for nearest neighbors which for each point x stores the list of points for which x is in the nearest neighbor list for the point. And if you want to always choose the next point which has the closest 9th nearest neighbor, and still beat O(N^2), you can keep your current set of points stored in a min heap ordered by distance to the 9th nearest neighbor, and update the heap when 10 points get removed. Of course, when the closest distance to the 9th nearest neighbor gets too large you'll need to use 8th nearest neighbors instead and start making clusters of 9 points. And then clusters of 8 points, etc. until finally you have a small set of outliers that you just make a cluster of one point each.